# Android WebView scaled font size

Tags: android, android-webview, font-size

In my application I have a dimension for a font defined as "18sp".  This font size is used in both a TextView (as a header) and a WebView (as body text).  On a mdpi device, both fonts look like they are the same size; however on a nexus 10 (xhdpi), the TextView looks correct while the WebView size doubles.  I'm setting the text size on the webview using

```
int fontSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textSize);
```

then setting the font using css in the body:

```
<body style='font-size: " + fontSize + "px'>
```

It's obvious why the text size is doubling - 18sp on an xhdpi device comes out to 36px - but I'm confused as to why this is handled automatically by the TextView and not by the WebView.  I can think of a couple of ways to handle this, but I don't know which (if any) is the right way:

- Separate font sizes for mdpi vs xhdpi devices
- Set the default zoom of the WebView to 100 / displayMetrics.scaledDensity
- Get the font size as an absolute integer (e.g. 18sp would equal 18) and set the font size to that number.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript code to change WebView style for fontSize, backgroundColor and font color. it's working.

```
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.fontSize ='11pt');");
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.backgroundColor ='red');");
loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.color ='yellow');");
```

Answer (score 0):

set font size like this in webview

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultFontSize(10);
```

Comment: I know how to set the size, the problem is getting the size in a way that makes sense.  The size is defined in a dimens resource, so my fontSize variable on an xhdpi device comes in as 36, which is not the right size for the default font size.  I need to get a size of 18 on both xhdpi and mdpi, so the question is the right way to get that value from the dimens resource.